# FB.login() called before calling FB.init()

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have seen this question in SO several times. Most of cases user called facebook js (all.js) twice or did not provide the application id. But my case is different. I have included all.js once and I also have set application id. But still I am getting this error "FB.login() called before calling FB.init()" when I click the login button. The markup for login button is as follows

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,user_about_me,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

And the javascript codes are

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FB.init({appId: '${section.parameters['facebook.app.id']}', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

        /* All the events registered */
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          // do something with response
          //logout();
        });

      function setFacebookStatus(form) {
            var status = $('#comment-form-body').val();
            var params = {};
            params['message']= status;
            params['link'] = '${article.url}';
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post',params, function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
              }
              else {
                alert('<fmt:message key="comment.form.facebook.success" />');
                $("#facebookComment").overlay().close();
                form.submit();
              }
            });
      }

    </script>
```

I have added all.js in the header of my html page. I am really pissed off this issue. I would be very grateful if you help me.

**Edit**

One more thing to mention. Sometimes it works and sometimes it shows me the warning. Say I was logged in to facebook from another tab and then I logged out from facebook. Then I refresh my website page that has the facebook integration. Then I get the warning. Main problem is that sometimes it is working sometimes not.

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors when the page loads that might prevent FB.init from being called?

Comment: No I am not getting any javascript error. One more thing to mention. Sometimes it works and sometimes it shows me the warning. Say I was logged in to facebook from another tab and then I logged out from facebook. Then I refresh my website page that has the facebook integration. Then I get the warning. Main problem is that sometimes it is working sometimes not.

Comment: Can you show a link to your page, or create an example that exhibits the issue?

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/CaMyw/2/

Comment: In the Facebook popup I get the message `An error occurred with sunjavax. Please try again later.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified my javascript as follows and now it is working.

```
    $(function() {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({appId: '${section.parameters['facebook.app.id']}', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        };
        $('body').append('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
        $.getScript(document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');
      })
```

*setFacebookStatus* function remain same. Adding those scripts on document ready removes the problem of facebook javascript warning and non deterministic login behavior. My guess is that on document ready initialization of FB scripts ensures execution of all calls in required order.